# Any solution for HMS Core audiokit sample error 2010008 If last HMS core from AppGallery is version 5.0.1.313 the same i installed already?

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

[Huawei Y7 Android 8 HMS core installed 5.0.1.313](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Apcxr.jpg)

I am testing audiokit HMS Core demo in Android Studio,de dependency
is 'com.huawei.hms:audiokit-player:1.0.0.302'

i am testing with Huawei Y7 device updated to Android 8 and with HMS core apk 5.0.1.313 (last from AppGallery) anyway launch this notification, HMS core update required ‍♂️ please somebody have any information about to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the update message is still displayed when HMS Core (APK) has been updated to the latest version is that Audio Kit (APK) needs to be downloaded.

When an app calls the Audio Kit API, HMS Core (APK) checks whether Audio Kit (APK) exists. If it does not exist, HMS Core (APK) prompts the user to update so that Audio Kit (APK) can be downloaded.

Please do the check as follows:

1. Check whether the update really succeeds when HMS Core (APK) displays an update success message.
2. If the update fails, please provide us with the region where your HUAWEI ID was registered. You can go to **Me** > **Settings** on AppGallery to find your region.

For more information, please visit [Audio Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/introduction-0000001050749665).